# Add method to a builtin class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to add an additional method to an existing type.

For example, I need to add an additional method "Transfer" to the type XmlDocument like `doc.AppendChild()`:

[image]

Comment: Extension Methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: I think you need this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610/c-net-prototype-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a method to an existing type (at least not without rewriting the IL of the assembly) but you can provide an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) which will at least look like a method of that class.